# CSS: Add spacing from fixed position item

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed-position element (red bar in this case) at top of the viewport. This element is positioned fixed so as it make it non-scrollable as required. It can have a dynamic height.

```
<div class="bar" id="bar">
</div>

.bar {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Below that element, there is a button that will toggle the red bar element's visibility.  This button should have a top space/ margin of a specific amount say 10px from the red bar when the red bar is displayed and the top space of 10px should be there from the window when the red bar is hidden.
This button should be scrollable.

```
<div class="btn-wrapper">
  <button onclick="toggleBar()">Toggle Bar</button>
</div>

.btn-wrapper {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Below the above button, there is a logo, which should have the same consistent space from the window top whether the red bar is present or not. The logo should be scrollable.

I have almost achieved these requirements except for one thing. I am not able to shift the button down when the red bar is present with the required margin as the red bar is positioned fixed. How this can be achieved?

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/abhi747/pen/PoWjxzK)

I have added the requirements comments in the codepen's HTML for the elements as well.

Note: The codepen/code which I have provided is for demo purposes. I am working on this for a React app and would prefer a pure CSS way for styling instead of JavaScript if possible.

Comment: I think you need to wrap toggle button and red bar together and position them fix. By this way the height of the red bar doesn't affect the position of toggle button. here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/homa_/pen/qBRjgWM

Comment: But then the toggle button is not scrollable which is required so

Answer (score 0):

You should to change margin-top as you're doing display block/none.
Just id to button:

```
<button id="button" onclick="toggleBar()">Toggle Bar</button>
```

and slightly modify javascript:

```
  const bar = document.getElementById("bar");
  const button = document.getElementById("button");
  bar.style.display = "none";

  function toggleBar() {
    if (bar.style.display === "none") {
      bar.style.display = "block";
      button.style.marginTop = "10px";
    } else {
      bar.style.display = "none";
      button.style.marginTop = "0px";
    }
  }
```

Working [codepen](https://codepen.io/tester-tester-the-bold/pen/gOgRqOY)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the codepen/code which I have provided is for demo purposes. I am working on this for a React app and would prefer a pure CSS way for styling instead of JavaScript if possible.

Comment: Since bar appears by click - it's required js anyway to style other elements.
As variant you can to modify class (I'm doing usually in html tag) and based on this class style button or anything other.

Comment: i.e.: when bar appears - add class to html element something like "bar_visible" and using this class you can style anything on page

Comment: Yeah. I got that. But the thing is that bar's height would be dynamic in the real app based on the content in it. So, just figuring how to provide a specific marginTop when the bar is visible.

Comment: in this case you can to get bar height and add value as marginTop, and it could be do only with js...

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing `position: fixed;` to `position: sticky;` on your `.bar` class CSS code. After that, to prevent the logo from moving, add the following CSS code:

```
.bar[style='display: block;'] ~ .logo {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

This should remove the margin from your logo upon detecting a visible `.bar` element before it.

Comment: Not quite. Sticky position works for the red bar and the button below it. But it breaks for the logo element as it shifts it upwards when there is no red bar displayed. The logo element should stay at its place consistently whether the red bar is present or not.

Comment: @AbhinandanKhilari I updated the answer with additional information. Please let me know if it works for you as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

use     `getBoundingClientRect().height`

apply to your 1st element

```
  button.style.marginTop = bar.getBoundingClientRect().height+'px';
```

Your code should

```
function toggleBar() {
  if (bar.style.display === "none") {
    bar.style.display = "block";
    
  } else {
    bar.style.display = "none";
  
  }
  button.style.marginTop = bar.getBoundingClientRect().height+'px';<------this single line enough
}
```

toggle simplified

```
bar.style.display=bar.style.display==='none'?'block':'none';
```

simplified code:

```
function toggleBar() {
 bar.style.display=bar.style.display==='none'?'block':'none';
 button.style.marginTop = bar.getBoundingClientRect().height+'px';<------this single line enough
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are:

- to move the button down 20px when the bar is showing without moving
  anything else
- to toggle the bar from display block to display none on alternate clicks of the button

There are two things that help here:

- making use of the JS toggle function on an element's classList
- CSS transform translate which will move an element without altering the layout of anything else

The JS is reduced to:

```
function toggleBar() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("hidebar");
  }
```

and the CSS has this added:

```
.hidebar div.bar {
  display: none; 
}

body:not(.hidebar) div.btn-wrapper {
  transform: translateY(20px);
}
```

You can use a different ancestor which is common to both bar and button if you prefer. body is just easy to use.

```js
function toggleBar() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("hidebar");
  }
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.bar {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-wrapper {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.logo {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.hidebar div.bar {
  display: none;
 
}

body:not(.hidebar) div.btn-wrapper {
  transform: translateY(20px);
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  This bar should appear/hide conditionally on click Toggle Bar button. 
  It will be always on top and not scrollable
-->
<div class="bar" id="bar">
</div>

<!-- 
  This should have top space of 10px from red bar when red bar is displayed and when red bar is hidden, the top space of 10px should be there from window. 
  This should be scrollable 
-->
<div class="btn-wrapper">
  <button onclick="toggleBar();">Toggle Bar</button>
</div>

<!--
  This should have same consistent space from window top whether the red bar is present or not.
  This should be scrollable.
-->
<div class="logo">
  Logo
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with only CSS is a bit tricky. But, luckily, `position: fixed` gives a way out.

Just because it's in the top doesn't mean it has to be the first element.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#top_wrapper {
  min-height: 95px;
}
#togglebutton {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#togglebutton_label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#togglebutton_label button {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.bar {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#togglebutton:checked ~ #bar {
    display: none;
}
#togglebutton:checked + #togglebutton_label {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top_wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" id="togglebutton">
  <label id="togglebutton_label" for="togglebutton">
    <button>Toggle Bar</button>
  </label>
  <div class="logo">
    Logo
  </div>
  <div class="bar" id="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere? Accusamus expedita excepturi placeat corporis culpa quod earum in nam, maxime odit sed facilis natus eligendi itaque nesciunt numquam accusantium non minus pariatur optio? Autem consequatur atque dolores dicta molestias!
  </p>
</div>
```

I wrapped the bar, the button and the logo in a div, where the button is first.

The button is in a label that's connected to an invisible checkbox.

Clicking the button sets the checkbox and then a selector can affect the following bar element.